# connecting to google talk through a bosh server using php

Tags: xmpp

I am creating my own php bosh connector so I
can attach() to strophe.  Here is my exchange and I'm getting a Bad
Authentication error (which is a google specific error).  The exchanges seem to be exactly the same as within
strophe when I connect with strophe successfully, do you know what is the problem?

```
<body rid='5559198240000' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'
to='babson.edu' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' window='5'
content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0'
xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>

string(500) "<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'
inactivity='60' secure='true' authid='BECF5BCD50577C01' content='text/xml;
charset=utf-8' window='5' polling='15'
sid='4ad843a8e15c79e34976783c96785bd5' requests='2'
wait='60'><stream:features xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'
xmlns='jabber:client'><mechanisms
xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mecha
nism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism></mechanisms>
</stream:features></body>"


<body rid='5559198240001' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'
sid='4ad843a8e15c79e34976783c96785bd5'><auth
xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'
mechanism='PLAIN'>same_base_64_translated_string_as_in_strophe=</auth></bod
y>

string(24) "Error=BadAuthentication
```

I've checked and the base_64 SASL encoded string is exactly the same as in my strophe logs where I connect successfully.  But my php program sending the same exact xml gets this BadAuthentication error.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong curl headers:

this is the correct way to use curl to speak with BOSH for anybody else that finds this post:

```
$ch = curl_init($bosh_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlpost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$header = array('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate','Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```